# Symfony - HTTP 404 not found and no route for "GET /"

Tags: symfony, http-status-code-404, pimcore

I dont know what to do, I cant find a solution. I installed a pimcore 5 demo on my server and got this two errors:
Symfony - HTTP 404 Not Found and 
No route found for "GET/".

Have anyone a idea or a solution?

Now i typed /admin/login in the url and got a 500 internal server error:

[image]

[image: Picture of this two errors]

[image: Error Picture]

[image: Error Picture of the Log]

[image: Error Picture]

LOG:

> ERROR 10:32:37 request    Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No
>   route found for "GET /"" at
>   /html/pimcore5/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php
>   line 125

Comment: Can you try to access the url without '/' in the end?

Comment: are you sure you have a route that match / ?

Comment: the url is pimcore5.intera.ws

Comment: [link] (http://pimcore5.intera.ws) and i get this 2 issues

Comment: can you edit your post with all the detail ? we don t understand anything of your problem

Comment: done, its now ok? or more details?

Comment: we can't guess your code and what you do to have the error. Explain your problem, not just put your error like we know your project

Comment: Its the first time i installed pimcore. Now i typed /admin/login in the url and got a 500 internal server error

Comment: database update required

Answer (score 0):

looks like you're missing the database, do doctrine:schema:update --force and see what that does and or run the migrations if there are any using the doctrine:migrations:migrate

additionally re: routing, maybe you're not including the routing correctly OR you need to add: [domainname]/app_dev.php/ ?